# How do I properly remove tabs and split in Python?

Tags: python, regex, formatting

I am using the following code to try to use the Fpgrowth algorithm but I get '' as items in the basket when I want to remove them. What is the proper way to do this?

```
from pyspark.mllib.fpm import FPGrowth
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]"))
data = sc.textFile("C:\\Users\\marka\\Downloads\\Assig2.txt")
data.map(lambda line: line.strip().split())
transactions = data.map(lambda line: line.strip().split('\t'))
#notempty = transactions.map(lambda x: x is not '')
unique = transactions.map(lambda x: list(set(x))).cache()
model = FPGrowth.train(unique, minSupport=0.7, numPartitions=10)
result = model.freqItemsets().collect()
for fi in result:
    print(fi)
```

Output:

```
FreqItemset(items=[''], freq=100)
FreqItemset(items=['Soap'], freq=99)
FreqItemset(items=['Soap', ''], freq=99)
FreqItemset(items=['Water'], freq=99)
FreqItemset(items=['Water', 'Soap'], freq=99)
FreqItemset(items=['Water', 'Soap', ''], freq=99)
FreqItemset(items=['Water', ''], freq=99)
FreqItemset(items=['Beer'], freq=88)
FreqItemset(items=['Beer', 'Water'], freq=88)
FreqItemset(items=['Beer', 'Water', 'Soap'], freq=88)
FreqItemset(items=['Beer', 'Water', 'Soap', ''], freq=88)
FreqItemset(items=['Beer', 'Water', ''], freq=88)
FreqItemset(items=['Beer', 'Soap'], freq=88)
FreqItemset(items=['Beer', 'Soap', ''], freq=88)
FreqItemset(items=['Beer', ''], freq=88)
FreqItemset(items=['Rock_Salt'], freq=80)
FreqItemset(items=['Rock_Salt', 'Water'], freq=79)
FreqItemset(items=['Rock_Salt', 'Water', 'Soap'], freq=79)
FreqItemset(items=['Rock_Salt', 'Water', 'Soap', ''], freq=79)
FreqItemset(items=['Rock_Salt', 'Water', ''], freq=79)
FreqItemset(items=['Rock_Salt', 'Soap'], freq=79)
FreqItemset(items=['Rock_Salt', 'Soap', ''], freq=79)
```

[image]

Comment: What is it you're trying to do ?

Comment: Sounds like you have to manipulate _model_ to get rid of those.

Comment: Why is this tagged “regex”? You’re just using string methods, and they seem to be working fine. Do you want to rewrite them to use regex instead? Or do you think it will help somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> s = 'Rock_Salt\tFlashlight\t\tWater\t\t'
>>> s.split('\t')
['Rock_Salt', 'Flashlight', '', 'Water', '', '']
>>> import re
>>> re.split(r'[\t]+', s)
['Rock_Salt', 'Flashlight', 'Water', '']

# potential solutions?
>>> [a for a in s.split('\t') if a]
['Rock_Salt', 'Flashlight', 'Water']
>>> list(filter(None, s.split('\t')))
['Rock_Salt', 'Flashlight', 'Water']
>>> s.split()
['Rock_Salt', 'Flashlight', 'Water']
```